# Distribution of the rows of a multinomial contingency table

Tags: discrete-data, contingency-tables

Suppose I have a multinomial contingency table like so

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\pi_{11} &\pi_{12} \\
\pi_{21} & \pi_{22}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Can I say anything about the distribution of the rows? Is the distribution of the first row Binomial with success probability $$p=\pi_{11} +\pi_{12}$$

Comment: You can say anything you like about the distributions, subject only to the constraints of the axioms of probability.  But that's an empty answer to an empty question.  What would give your question meaning and interest would be some context: what does this table represent and what is your basis for supposing that its entries ought to be modeled as random variables?  And what exactly do you mean by the "rows"?  Would that refer to the row *sums*?

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $X,Y$ are independent and if $X$ is distributed like $Bin(n,p)$ and $Y$ like $Bin(m,p)$, then $X+Y$ is distributed like $Bin(n+m,p)$. However if say $Y$ is distributed like $Bin(m,q)$ where $p\neq q$, then the sum is no longer binomial.